# Como inserir uma keyword em uma busca no banco já realizada

Tags: php, query, mysqli, order-by, prepared-statement

Por exemplo, fiz uma busca de todos os dados do usuário no banco pra dar echo em diferentes colunas pelo site:

```
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $usu_codigo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $usu_info_result = $stmt->get_result();
    $usu_info_coluna = $usu_info_result->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();
```

Em outro lugar do site, eu queria mostrar esse resultado, porém, usando um ORDER BY ou LIMIT, como:

```
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_codigo = ? ORDER BY usu_datacadastro DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Como eu posso fazer isso sem ter que preparar outra query, já que já tenho o resultado e só quero filtrar a saída?

Comment: Num dá para chamar o `result` na página que você quer e pegar dele só o que você quer?

Comment: @MagicHat Então, a parte de pegar colunas específicas eu sei fazer, mas filtrar com um order by ou limit é que não sei a sintaxe.

Comment: Hum... é uma dúvida específica de `sql` então?

Comment: Creio que sim...

Comment: Mas tá dando erro essa query sua?

Comment: Não, a query funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que quero exibir os resultados da primeira query em outro lugar, sem ter que preparar outra query, já que os dados que eu quero, já foram buscados na primeira query, só quero formatar com um order by

Comment: Tipo, você quer exportar o valor armazenado de uma variável para outra página, ex: faz  
a query em uma página e em outra puxa esses valores?

Comment: isso, quero puxar o valor da query, só que ordenar  o resultado, sem ter a necessidade de criar outra query

Comment: acredito que você armazenará os dados retornados no _select_ inicial em um _array_.. então pode usar alguma [dessas funções](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)

Comment: Então eu dei uma lida nessas funções, mas acredito que tenha errado a sintaxe várias vezes porque não consegui aplicar no meu código, pode me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho reputação suficiente para comentar, então te pergunto: pode me confirmar se todos os usuários foram armazenados como array na variável $usu_info_coluna? E qual é a estrutura dos dados?

```
print_r($usu_info_coluna);
```

O normal é utilizar um while com o fetch_assoc para recuperar cada resultado colocando em um array, deste modo:

```
function listaProdutos($conexao) {
    $produtos = array(); // aqui criamos um array vazio
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from produtos"); // aqui selecionamos todos os produtos do nosso banco

    while($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { // aqui dizemos que enquanto houver produtos no nosso resultado realizaremos a logica a seguir
        array_push($produtos, $produto); // finalmente colocamos nosso produto dentro do array de produtos
}
```

Mas acredito que o seu objeto já esteja realizando esta lógica e levando todos os resultados para a variável $usu_info_coluna. Partindo deste princípio, vamos a solução:

LIMIT 5 -> Ao publicar os resultados, basta imprimir somente a quantidade que você precisa:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    echo "Data: " . $usu_info_coluna[$i][usu_datacadastro] . "Nome: " . $usu_info_coluna[$i][usu_nome];
}
```

Comment: Sim, o objeto já está na array, mas não consigo passar da parte de imprimir, ele me retorna Undefines offset, seguindo seu exemplo, só que os nomes estão corretos

Comment: eu consegui limitar usando o while, mas como ficaria a sintaxe para ordenar os resultados por alguma coluna?

Comment: Você precisa utilizar uma [função de ordenação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php) em um array preparado com seus dados, já que a ordenação é feita por coluna. Coloque na pergunta o estrutura da variável com os resultados que coloco o código pra você.